# Disable only checked checkboxes Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTUyf.png)**Is there any chance that I can disable the selected/Checked Items on p-listbox In angular 8?
Either by adding  or on CSS. When I tried to add [disabled]  property on  the complete list of items are being disabled where as I wish to disable only those items on list which are checked.
**[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpwiQ.png)

```html
<div class="ui-g">
     <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-2">
       <label>Fields</label>
     </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-6">
     <p-listbox *ngIf="!datasetLoader" [options]="mandatoryField" [(ngModel)]="selectedField" 
           [listStyle]="{'max-height':'150px'}" (onChange)="fieldSelection($event)" multiple="multiple" 
           formControlName="field" checkbox="checkbox" optionLabel="DisplayFieldName">
     </p-listbox>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can add [disabled]="checked"

Answer (score 0):

the p-listbox option is base of the primeng **SelectItem** interface , and there is an property of the SelectItem interface called disable if it set to true the option related to that items will be disabled.

*template*

```html
<p-listbox [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
          [listStyle]="{'max-height':'250px'}" multiple="multiple"
    (ngModelChange)="updateItems($event)" checkbox="checkbox">
</p-listbox>
```

*component*

```js
  updateItems(selectedItems:string[]) {
      selectedItems.forEach(v =>{
        let car = this.cars.find( c => c.value === v); 
        car.disabled = true; 
      })
    }
```

> every time you have select an item we will update that option disable property to true

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-listbox-demo-ggqdac?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: thank you for the answer. But the is conflict I could see is, that the interface of SelectItem of primeNg and the interface that I created for my API isn't matching and because of that when I check an Item and try to save using Post method and get back to same page/component screen the previous checked items are being Un-checked.

Comment: you need to convert your api respond to match primeng SelectItem  simply the label and value you can check the interface here https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/api/selectitem.ts